# Can VPN into Pi but No Internet

Tags: vpn

I set up a VPN server on my Pi3 following the same steps that I did in Ubuntu ([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)). I use that VPN server daily without issue.

I can successfully connect to the VPN, but I cannot get to the internet. I have tried or checked:

- disabling ufw
- `/etc/default/ufw` to include `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`
- `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` --> `1`
- `sudo nano /etc/openvpn/server.conf` contains without comments:

  - `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`
  - `push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"`
  - `push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"`
- I then read some posts about changing `iptables` which I did not have to do in ubuntu, but gave it a shot anyway (not really knowing what I am doing here)

  - `sudo /sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` and
  - `sudo /sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
- Another `iptables` edit:

  - `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.107.3`
- ssh into the pi and can `ping google.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't follow the same guide as you but have a similar setup. Try the following:

Clear out your old rules with these commands

```
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
```

Add this single iptables rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Alternatively http://www.pivpn.io takes all the heavy lifting out of the equation with their rather helpful script.

Comment: Thanks but did not work. Had to do `-F` first (which booted me from my ssh) bc `-X` had `iptables: Too many links.` but then went back and did `-X`. Any other ideas? I would like to get it working without pivpn if possible...

Comment: When I check `sudo iptables -L` and `-S` I do not see the rule you have me add. Should I? Where else can I look?

Comment: Got it to work by changing `eth0` to `wlan0` as I am connected over wireless. Should have caught that. Followed the instructions at this link to add a boot script that does the iptables automatically. https://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing/